# Error haciendo una consulta SQL con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, nodejs

estoy intentando hacer un SELECT desde node.js para obtener un error de una tabla de "errores" pero obtengo el siguiente error y ya no se que mas hacer o a que se debe.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Could not find stored
>   procedure 'S@param1L'.

Este es el codigo que uso:

```
function BD_Connection(err){
  var conn = sql.connect(config, function(err, request){
    var message = "Codigo error: BD0001 \nDescripcion: Error al conectar con la base de datos \nFuncion: BD_Connection()";
  if(err) {
    //throw new error(message);
    console.log(err)
  }else{
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM Error WHERE Error_Code = DB0002",function(err, result){
      if(err){
        console.log("Error")
      }else{
        console.log(result)
      }
    })
  }
  })
}
```

En este metodo llamo a esa funcion:

```
app.listen(3001, function(err, res){
  if(err){
    console.log("Error")
  }else{
    console.log('Im listening');

  }  
  let fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('config/config.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    var NewConfig = JSON.parse(data);
    config = NewConfig;
    BD_Connection("DB0002");
}
});
});
```

Alguien sabe a que se ppuede deber? Gracias.

Comment: tienes mal escrito SELECT te falta una E

Comment: Listo, de igual forma da el error

Comment: podrías indicarnos por favor donde mandas llamar a ese store procedure que marca el error?

Comment: Listo, modifique la pregunta.

Comment: El parametro para `Error_Code` no debiese ir entre comillas? `SELECT * FROM Error WHERE Error_Code = 'DB0002'`